# Python Kivy Accordion

Tags: android, python, accordion, kivy

I'm using kivy for development android application with python.However I can not working kivy-designer.
I can download modul in [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer). I installed everything neccessary.I upgraded kivy version.

when I run 'python main.py', I get this error;

```
 AccordionException: Accordion: instance not found in children
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2012, in _apply_rule
     setattr(widget_set, key, value)
   File "weakproxy.pyx", line 22, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__setattr__ (/tmp/pip-build-cdY5Fu/kivy/kivy/weakproxy.c:1205)
   File "properties.pyx", line 397, in kivy.properties.Property.__set__ (/tmp/pip-build-cdY5Fu/kivy/kivy/properties.c:4530)
   File "properties.pyx", line 429, in kivy.properties.Property.set (/tmp/pip-build-cdY5Fu/kivy/kivy/properties.c:5012)
   File "properties.pyx", line 484, in kivy.properties.Property.dispatch (/tmp/pip-build-cdY5Fu/kivy/kivy/properties.c:5628)
   File "_event.pyx", line 1168, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (/tmp/pip-build-cdY5Fu/kivy/kivy/_event.c:11685)
   File "_event.pyx", line 1074, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (/tmp/pip-build-cdY5Fu/kivy/kivy/_event.c:11022)
   File "/home/oruc/kivy-designer/designer/uix/playground_size_selector.py", line 32, in on_playground
     self.view = PlaygroundSizeView(selected_size=self.playground.size)
   File "/home/oruc/kivy-designer/designer/uix/playground_size_selector.py", line 170, in __init__
     self.update_buttons()
   File "/home/oruc/kivy-designer/designer/uix/playground_size_selector.py", line 197, in update_buttons
     self.accordion.select(btn.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/accordion.py", line 379, in select
     'Accordion: instance not found in children')
```

Kivy is working with my android phone.But I can not working kivy-designer.

Comment: Kivy designer is currently in an early and unstable state, under active development by a gsoc student. Your best chance for help will probably be to ask in the #kivy channel on freenode, but you'll probably need to look into and potentially solve such issues yourself for now.

Comment: Okey, I solved errors.
https://github.com/ahmetkotan/kivy-designer
I sent pull request to kivy:master.